# Which is easier to learn: AccuRev or Perforce?

Tags: perforce, accurev

We are trying to decide between AccuRev or Perforce. We have a small team, and need something that is easy to learn. Which of these version control applications is easier to learn and more user friendly?

Answer (score 3):

Neither one is easy to learn.  Perforce's weirdness is focused around branching and private work areas.  AccuRev's weirdness is focused around streams, promoting between them, and reparenting them.  Both systems are a little hard to get your head around, especially if you're used to CVS.

For my two cents, AccuRev is the better product.  The streams are a very powerful tool for managing development vs. QA vs. patches.  And the concept of server-shadowed private workspaces is a godsend - there is no reason for a user not to checkpoint their workspace several times a day, and it goes into your server backups.

Comment: Thanks Ross. We currently use SVN, and we have a very small development team, so I want something that is easy to use and maintain. I'm wondering if both of these are more than we need. Do you know if very small teams (2 to 4 developers)  use these apps?

Comment: Yes, they're both overkill, and yes, you can use both with small teams.  I've used AccuRev with a team of 10 developers and my CTO said "we couldn't have built [our product] without it".  I've used Perforce with two teams of 3-5 developers.  But the simple truth is, fancy revision control systems prove their worth only when developers often modify the same files and you need to reconcile changes.  If Fred works on the UI, Joe works on the web services, and Barb works on the DB, you probably can get by with SVN just fine.

Comment: For what it's worth, Perforce will be implementing streams later this year http://blog.perforce.com/blog/?p=4615.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still choosing you may want to read [AccuRev - another story how to screw UI](http://pabich.eu/blog/archive/2008/01/30/accurev---another-story-how-to-screw-ui.aspx) and [Reply by AccuRev](http://blog.accurev.com/2008/02/06/accurev-gui-love-or-hate-just-communicate/). As an AccuRev user, I think that idea of stream tree is really powerful and many of the features like time locks, promoting by transactions or issues, etc. are useful, but UI implementation is awful. You definitely need to play hard with it before switching.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for AccuRev - honestly I haven't even heard of it before now - but I can speak for Perforce:

I find it incredibly easy once you understand a few truly key aspects:

- Anything that might change the "depot" (server side SCM managed repository) happens through changelists.
- All of those interactions on changelists are also tied to a client workspace - in other words, you can't really work with files that haven't had a mapping established from the depot to your filesystem.

Also, the three days of training in San Francisco (or perhaps a closer location) was well worth it for me as I have an administrative role in our Perforce environment - though I had been using it prior to the training just fine to manage our code base.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit subjective!

That being said, there are many variables you need to consider: developer experience, what tool you are currently using, what your team can afford to buy etc.

If your main concern is simply figuring out what is easier, both vendors offer free trials/licenses. You should download them and test them out against your code base and existing tools.

Also - try to get your team involved to ease the transition.